# Foreach(){} stops after 1st row

Tags: php, loops, pdo, foreach

I'm just trying to loop through my DB and I get only the 1st row.
this is my database PHP:

**database.class.php:**

```
<?php
     $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=testing070416', 'root', 'root1');
     $statement = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM users");
     $rows = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
     var_dump($rows);
?>
```

And the **index.php**:

```
<?php include ('database.class.php');?>
   <table border="1">
      <?php foreach ($rows as $value=>$key ){
               echo '<tr><th style="color: red;">'.$value.'</th>';
               echo '<td>'.$key.'</td></tr>';
            }
      ?>
```

the result:

[image]

There's supposed to be 4 more IDs to loop on.

Thanks!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php - http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Comment: [**RTM**: `->fetch()` - Fetches the next **row** from a result set](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php). If you want multiple rows either use [`fetchAll`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) or use `fetch` in a while loop.

Comment: ^ *my sentiments exactly*

Comment: But now i'm getting "array" in every cell. http://i.imgur.com/x9zrlT3.png

Comment: @Erez.Matrix check the output of your var dump and you will understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `fetchAll` instead of `fetch`

Change from

```
$rows = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Into

```
$rows = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Then code for your `index.php`

```
<table border="1">
<?php
for($i = 0; $i == count($rows); $i++)
{
    foreach($rows[$i] as $value=>$key )
    {
        echo '<tr><th style="color: red;">'.$value.'</th>';
        echo '<td>'.$key.'</td></tr>';
    }
}
?>
```

**Difference between `fetch` and `fetchAll`**

`fetch` actually fetches the next row from a result set.

`fetchAll` returns an array containing all of the result set rows.

Comment: Salam Aleikum Hassaan, the code has changed and is running but with empty cells: i.imgur.com/x9zrlT3.png

Comment: Walikum Salam, I have updated my answer but code is not tested. Let me know if it does not works for you.

Answer (score 2):

Use fetchAll instead of fetch to get all results.

Change:

`$rows = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

To:

`$rows = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`